# buttons and dialogs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dialog

I have an button(lets assume it name is 123) and if I press on it then a dialog window (lets assumebr window1) will appear. Window1  has 1 button. If I press the button then another dialog window appers, which also has 1 button and 2 radio buttons. After the user makes his decision and presses button 2, then both dialog windows should disappear.

I use

```
$("dialog1").remove();
$("dialog2").remove();
```

After that if I want to press 123 again, then first (and consequently tse second) window not appears. `.detach()` is not what I need.
Everything is in the same session. How can I make then to appear again? What methods should I use?

Comment: have you tried $("dialog1").hide();

Comment: yes, but then i need to use .show() what I do not want to use

Answer (score 0):

`$.hide()` and `$.show()`, respectively - if you don't want to use them, please update your question and explain why those (or `.detatch()`) aren't viable options. The alternative is to recreate the DOM elements, for example using `$("<div id="dialog1">stuff</div>");`, but this is very inefficient compared to hide/show and/or detach.